# Hide form when minimize doesn't work in Visual C#

Tags: c#

I'm lookin for examples how hide form when I minimize, but this.Hide() doesn't work. I don't understand what's wrong. At the moment I just want to hide Form1.

```
    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

When I click in minimize button, form goes to taskbar but form doesn't hide.

Comment: `WindowState` changes after you call `Hide`, not before

Comment: Did you add a `NotifyIcon` to the form?

Comment: Yes. I have a notifyIcon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. After InitializeComponent():

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Resize += SetMinimizeState;

    }
```

Then:

```
    private void SetMinimizeState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool isMinimized = this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = !isMinimized;
        if (isMinimized)
        {
            // optional
            notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(500, "Title", "Message.", ToolTipIcon.Info);
        }
    }
```

It works!